# How to make font variables that can be reused in scss

Tags: css, angular, sass, fonts

I am working on an Angular project and we use scss. We want to standardize our use of fonts throughout the application. For eg. Instead of using `font-family: Arial` everywhere it should be `font-family: $arialFont`.

In my current **styles.css** we have the following.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica_Neue_Light";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueLight.eot");
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueLight.eot")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/woff/HelvNeueLight.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/tff/HelvNeueLight.ttf") format("ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica_Neue_Medium";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueMedium.eot");
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueMedium.eot")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/woff/HelvNeueMedium.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/tff/HelvNeueMedium.ttf") format("ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica_Neue_Bold";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueBold.eot");
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueBold.eot")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/woff/HelvNeueBoldfor.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/tff/HelvNeueBold.ttf") format("ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica_Neue_Light_Italics";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueLightItalic.eot");
  src: url("./assets/fonts/eot/HelvNeueLightItalic.eot")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/woff/HelvNeueLightItalic.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/tff/HelvNeueLightItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

These are simply used as `font-family: 'Helvetica_Neue_Bold'` or `font-family: 'Helvetica_Neue_Light_Italics'` in the other scss files. The disadvantage of this is whenever we need to change the font for the app we need to make a change in every single instance. So I need a way to assign each font family name to a variable and use it everywhere so that the next time there is a font change, i only have to change the value of variables in one place,

I have created a **fonts.scss** where I've put

```
$helvetica-neue-light: "Helvetica_Neue_Light";
$helvetica-neue-medium: "Helvetica_Neue_Medium";
$helvetica-neue-bold: "Helvetica_Neue_Bold";
$helvetica-neue-light-italics: "Helvetica_Neue_Light_Italics";
```

I imported it in the first file, **styles.css** and assigned the variables to `font-family`. But now I have to import **fonts.scss** in every single scss file, which is also troublesome. Is there another way to do this task? Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you use sass, then you have to import the file where the variables are defined into every file where you want to use these variables.

An alternative is to use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). You can declare them in once place and reuse them without import.

**styles.scss**

```
:root
{
  /** hard coded **/
  --helvetica-neue-light: "Helvetica_Neue_Light";
  --helvetica-neue-medium: "Helvetica_Neue_Medium";
  /** or use sass variable**/
  --helvetica-neue-light-italics: $helvetica-neue-light-italics;
}
```

**component.scss**

```
div
 {
   font-family: var(--helvetica-neue-light);
 }
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-towfjc)

**Note:** this will not work with IE

Comment: Ohh. I am importing the file where I have declared the font variables. I thought there might be another way, I'm not as familiar with scss. Thanks!